# LDAP Server on Heroku?

Tags: ruby, http, ldap, heroku

Is it possible to run the LDAP protocol over HTTP or HTTPS?

If so, does anybody know of a Ruby LDAP server which can be made to run on Heroku.com?

Comment: Running an LDAP server in the cloud sounds like overkill (for a web app), or a very bad idea (for an institutional network).  What are you planning on using it for?

Comment: @mikerobi - I want to get a toy OmniAuth app with the LDAP strategy working against a real LDAP server.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to run LDAP over HTTP(S). LDAP is a binary protocol in its own right, described in ASN.1 and transmitted in BER. However, [DSML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_Service_Markup_Language) provides some functionality that may interest you. DSML represents directory services information using XML.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, certainly it is possible, I have one where LDAP entities are sent as JSON objects. Let me know if you are interested in taking a look at it. But this is in Java not Ruby but might throw some light..